# Equilibrium distribution exponentially fast

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains

I need to prove that for an aperiodic, irreducible Markov Chain $X_n$ with stationary distribution $\pi$ holds that $P_x[X_n=j]\to\pi(j)$ exponentially fast. I found some proof of that statement but using reversibility of $\pi$ which I do not want to assume. Does some one knows a good reference for that?

Alternatively, using the coupling proof of the convergence statement is there a way of saying that the stopping time of the coupling has an exponential distribution?

Comment: If you have a finite state space $\mathcal{S}$, then aperiodicity and irreducibility imply there is a positive integer $m$, a probability $p>0$, and a state (call it "0") such that $P[X_{n+m}=0|X_n=i]\geq p$ for all $i \in \mathcal{S}$. It follows that two independent chains traversing the same state space will meet after $m$ steps with probability at least $p^2$, independent of history.  So the probability of not meeting after $km$ steps is at most $(1-p^2)^k$, so it decays exponentially fast.  This can be used with the coupling argument to show "exponentially fast"  coupling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sketch: use irreducibility to conclude that there is only one stationary distribution. Use aperiodicity to conclude that there are no other eigenvalues of modulus $1$ other than $1$. Use Gerschgorin's theorem to conclude that there no eigenvalues of modulus *larger* than $1$ (maybe this is obvious).

Now if the transition probability matrix were diagonalizable, then you would be done. If not, then largest possible entry (other than the $1$ corresponding to the stationary distribution) in the Jordan form of $P^n$ is $n^{|S|-1} \lambda^n$ where $|S|$ is the number of states and $\lambda$ is the next largest eigenvalue away from $1$. Asymptotically this decays faster than, say, $\left ( \frac{|\lambda|+1}{2} \right )^n$, which is exponentially fast.